# Schengen Visa Granted for only 31 days

Tags: visas, schengen, schengen-visas

So I applied a tourist visa thinking that the visa duration will remain 90 days regardless of my intended travel date.

As far as I understand the main point is how many days I am staying. Although the validity or the expired date seems to be the constraint for me.

My visa is valid from October 1st 2022- November 15th 2022 with the duration date of 31 days. However I planned to travel a little later than that but still manage to stay within 31 days. The problem is my intended departure date is way beyond Nov. 15. Will there be a problem when I depart?

Would like to note that my final country destination will be in Portugal.

Comment: 90 days are the exception than rule for most visa nationals. You cannot stay past the expiration date on your Schengen visa.

Comment: Sounds as if your given itinerary in the application was for 3 weeks, since they generally add 10 days to that.